# Accessing the UITableViewCell UIButton, Custom Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

When I press a button in my `UItableViewCell` the target action gets fired and there I need to display an image in another button within the same cell. My code is below but it is giving me an error because of my custom `UITableViewCell` class. Is there a way around this?

Error is:

`incompatible pointer types, initializing CUSTOM_CELL with an expression of type UITableViewCell`.

My `CUSTOM_CELL` is of :`UItableViewCell`

```
NSIndexPath *path = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndex:[sender tag]];
CUSTOM_CELL *cell = [self.TABLE cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];

[cell.BUTTON setImage:IMG_check forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**`UITableView CellForRowAtIndexPath`**

```
        //inits
        CUSTOM_CELL *cell = (CUSTOM_CELL *)
        [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell_item"];

        if (cell == nil){
            cell = [[CUSTOM_CELL alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                          reuseIdentifier:@"cell_item"];}

        //init the add button
        //*************************************************************


        [cell.BUTTON addTarget:self
                               action:@selector(SelectorMethod:)
                     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: CUSTOM_CELL is a subclass of UITableViewCell ?

Comment: Yes it subclasses the UItableViewCell

Comment: Show some more code, not getting why you have used "NSIndexPath *path = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndex:[sender tag]];" line.

Comment: [sender tag] is the current index path of the cell I want to access, its the target action assigned to the button during the cellForRowAtIndexPath tableview loading method.

Comment: Do follow **CamelCase** Naming convention while naming your class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely your use of `NSIndexPath`.

Assuming the `tag` of your button is the row number it is in and you only have one section, try this:

```
NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0];
```

Comment: That code does not work. The error Xcode provides says that the problem is "incompatible pointer types, initializing CUSTOM_CELL with an expression of type UITableViewCell". But I don't yet see a work around for that.

Comment: Post your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. The error is clear. You are not creating a cell of the right type.

Comment: Type cast your cell by adding this- (CUSTOM_CELL*) like---    CUSTOM_CELL *cell = (CUSTOM_CELL * )[self.TABLE cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];

Comment: I tried casting, but it does not work. Get a new error "Used type CUSTOM_CELL where arithmetic or pointer type is required".

Comment: I think you have used (CUSTOM_CELL) in place of (CUSTOM_CELL*).

Comment: Yup! Just got it. But without errors, the image is not being displayed in the button.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved with casting and correction of assigning an accurate index path

```
CUSTOM_CELL *cell = (CUSTOM_CELL*)[self.TABLE cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```